# How to align element in div independently of the others in css?

Tags: html, css

So i've got div looking like this. My question is how can I align **h1** so it stays always on top of this div and rest of content is aligned in the middle of div like how it is now?

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
   <h1>INFO</h1>
   <div class="info"><h2>Age</h2><p>20</p></div>
   <div class="info"><h2>Adress</h2><p>Wolna 23, Warszawa</p></div>
   <div class="info"><h2>Email</h2><p>lorem@gmail.com</p></div>
   <div class="info"><h2>Phone</h2><p>669 133 777</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container
{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 35.5%;
    height: 550px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.info
{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: whats the problem exactly? your code do this for you already

Comment: I want h1 to be at the top of div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. We can solve this issue with the help of `flex`, without using `position: absolute;`.

1. You need to remove `justify-content: center;` from the `.container`.
2. We have wrapped all `info` items in one div like `.content` and give `margin:auto;` to them.

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/z71rbu6o/7/

```css
.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35.5%;
  height: 550px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #000;
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.content {
  margin: auto;
}
.info {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.info h2,
.info p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>INFO</h1>
  <div class="content">
  <div class="info">
      <h2>Age</h2>
      <p>20</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Adress</h2>
      <p>Wolna 23, Warszawa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Email</h2>
      <p>lorem@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Phone</h2>
      <p>669 133 777</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works how I wanted, thank you so much :)

Comment: We are glad that, our solution helped you...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stick it to the top add this:

```
h1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Edit:** there are a lot of ways, but in all of them you must to take the header out of the flexbox. You can do it like this:

```css
  .container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 35.5%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: coral;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .info {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  }

  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 450px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 100%;

  }

  .header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: cadetblue;
  }

  p {
    margin: 0.5rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="header">INFO</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Age</h2>
      <p>20</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Adress</h2>
      <p>Wolna 23, Warszawa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Email</h2>
      <p>lorem@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Phone</h2>
      <p>669 133 777</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I have other divs similiar to the one i put here. This would take theirs h1's and put them on the top of whole site. I want them to be at the top of individual div in which they are in. Hope you understand me :)

Comment: yes, I understand. but using just a flexbox you can not do that all. look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```css
.container h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0vh;
}
```